# ¿Cómo resolver el error "Navigation action/destination android:id/home cannot be found" en Android?

Tags: java, android, navigationview

Estoy implementando el Componente de Navegación en Android y tengo un problema sólo en un punto.

Todo funciona bien, pero cuando pulso **el botón de retroceso de la barra superior** aparece esto error en la consola (como dato a tener en cuenta, el mensaje no aparece si pulso **el botón de retroceso físico del dispositivo**):

> I/NavigationUI: Ignoring onNavDestinationSelected for MenuItem
> android:id/home as it cannot be found from the current destination
> Destination(org.my.app:id/nav_tercia) label=Tercia
> class=org.my.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination android:id/home cannot be found from the current destination
> Destination(org.my.app:id/nav_tercia) label=Tercia
> class=org.my.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1650)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1582)
> at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.kt:96)
> at org.deiverbum.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment$1.onMenuItemSelected(BreviarioDataFragment.java:108)
> at androidx.core.view.MenuHostHelper.onMenuItemSelected(MenuHostHelper.java:107)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ComponentActivity.java:553)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:264)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:269)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:110)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:188)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)

La App vuelve al fragmento anterior, pero quiero quitar ese mensaje, signo de que algo no anda bien.

Este es el método del Fragmento donde ocurre el problema:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
            voiceItem=menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz);
            voiceItem.setVisible(isVoiceOn);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_voz) {
                //Algunas cosas que necesito aquí
                requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;
            }
            NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(requireParentFragment());
            return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
        }
    }, getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);

    binding = FragmentBreviarioDataBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    // ...
    return root;
}
```

Depurando, el problema son estas dos líneas:

```
            NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(requireParentFragment());
            return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
```

Si las cambio por un `return false;` el mensaje antes descrito no aparece, pero **no me funcionan algunas opciones que tengo en la barra superior y que tengo integradas al Componente de Navegación**.

En el XML `navigation` el Fragmento tiene este destino asignado:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_tercia"
    android:name="org.deiverbum.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_fragment_tercia"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_breviario_data" >
    <argument
        android:name="hourId"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="3" />
</fragment>
```

Traté de agregar también esto dentro de `fragment` para ver si reconocía la navegación a `home`, pero nada:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/home"
        app:destination="@id/home" />
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error que estás viendo en la consola indica que se está intentando navegar a un destino que no se encuentra en la gráfica de navegación actual. En este caso, parece que estás tratando de navegar a un destino que tiene un ID de "home", pero ese destino no se encuentra en la gráfica de navegación actual.

La solución a este problema es asegurarte de que el destino con ID "home" esté incluido en la gráfica de navegación actual. Si quieres que el botón de retroceso de la barra superior navegue hacia el inicio de la aplicación (por ejemplo, la pantalla principal), puedes agregar un destino en el archivo XML de la gráfica de navegación con el ID "home" y configurarlo para que navegue al inicio de la aplicación. Por ejemplo:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/home"
android:name="org.my.app.ui.fragments.HomeFragment"
android:label="@string/title_home" >
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_home_to_nav_tercia"
    app:destination="@id/nav_tercia" />
```

Aquí, se ha agregado un destino con el ID "home" que apunta al fragmento "HomeFragment". Además, se ha definido una acción que va desde el destino "home" al destino "nav_tercia", que es el destino actual de tu fragmento.

Luego, en el método "onCreateView()" de tu fragmento, puedes usar el NavController para navegar hacia el destino "home" cuando se presione el botón de retroceso de la barra superior. Por ejemplo:

```
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) 
requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
         NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
Toolbar toolbar = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        navController.navigate(R.id.home);
    }
});
```

Aquí, he configurado el NavController para que navegue hacia el destino "home" cuando se presione el botón de retroceso de la barra superior. También se ha configurado el NavigationUI para que muestre el título correcto en la barra superior según el destino actual.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El inconveniente que veo es que tengo un montón de destinos en la misma situación y tendría que hacer lo mismo en todos ellos. Plantee la pregunta también en SO en inglés, y [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75922225/5587982) más simple hasta ahora ha sido, en el Fragmento, controlar la ocurrencia `android.R.id.home` en `onMenuItemSelected()` poniendo un `return false` en ese caso.